# Google form RegEx for time

Tags: google-forms

I don't want to use the time field in Google Forms, and have tried to create a RexEx like this:

`[\0-24]{2}:[\0-59]{2}`

It accept "*21:35*", but rejects input like "**07:35**" og "**17:35**".

Any idea why it behave like this?

Answer (score 0):

This is the RegEx:

```
[0-2]{1}[0-9]{1}:[0-5]{1}[0-9]{1}
```

Source: https://www.regextester.com